# amix filter is causing audio to disappear

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying overlay audio onto a video. I have a very simple ffmpeg command (`auido.mp3` is much longer than the video)

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a] [1:a] amix=duration=shortest [a]" -map 0:v -map [a] test.mp4
```

This produces a silent video. However, when not mapping the video stream

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a] [1:a] amix=duration=shortest [a]" -map [a] test.mp4
```

The resulting audio file is as expected.

What could be causing this issues?

(Is there a better way to overlay audio onto a video via ffmpeg?)

Edit: log

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-11-15T05:28:05.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:00.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9463 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 9546 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-15T05:28:05.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-15T05:28:05.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
[mp3 @ 000001fdf5f7f040] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'audio.mp3':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2019-11-14 23:31
    id3v2_priv.XMP  : <?xpacket begin="\xef\xbb\xbf" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>\x0a<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c148 79.163765, 2019/01/24-18:11:46        ">\x0a <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">\x0a  <rdf
  Duration: 00:22:01.91, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> amix:input0 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (mp3float) -> amix:input1 (graph 0)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  amix (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] 264 - core 158 r2984 3759fcb - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-15T05:28:05.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
frame=   15 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     695kB time=00:00:00.40 bitrate=14232.7kbits/s speed=0.437x    
video:693kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.226150%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] frame I:1     Avg QP:30.52  size:101545
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] frame P:7     Avg QP:28.22  size: 44755
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] frame B:7     Avg QP:30.76  size: 42074
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] consecutive B-frames: 20.0% 40.0% 40.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] mb I  I16..4: 68.3% 10.5% 21.2%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] mb P  I16..4: 17.6%  4.8%  4.3%  P16..4: 28.5%  4.5%  2.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:37.6%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] mb B  I16..4: 17.6%  2.4%  1.3%  B16..8: 37.9%  6.7%  1.3%  direct: 4.9%  skip:27.8%  L0:40.5% L1:54.3% BI: 5.2%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] 8x8 transform intra:13.9% inter:59.5%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 54.5% 53.3% 42.3% inter: 15.3% 27.8% 21.6%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] i16 v,h,dc,p:  5% 88%  5%  2%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 53% 29%  1%  1%  1%  2%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  6% 80%  9%  1%  1%  0%  1%  0%  2%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] i8c dc,h,v,p: 16% 80%  3%  1%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] ref P L0: 40.3%  4.9% 11.0% 43.8%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] ref B L0: 80.0% 11.1%  8.9%
[libx264 @ 000001fdf64ab700] kb/s:11349.57
[aac @ 000001fdf64ac600] Qavg: 41522.195
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan added | c h a r a c t e r l i m i t